# JS element onclick event not being fired

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have an <a> element, which I have selected using the dom. I have the following code:

```
var link = document.createElement("a");
var ce = function (e) {
   alert("A");
}
link.onclick = ce; // Or link.addEventListener("click", ce);
console.log(ce);
console.log(link.onlick);
```

In the console (chrome dev tools), I see the following:

```
function (e) { alert("A"); }
```

and then

```
undefined
```

Upon clicking the element, the event does not fire. I have noticed that applying the onclick to the same element from the console, however, *does* correctly apply the event.

How to I get this event to apply?

Comment: well, what is `link`?

Comment: `var link = document.createElement("a");`

Comment: Undefined because you mispelled onclick.

Comment: @HanletEscaño and that is a wierd event :)

Comment: @AmitJoki unless touch screens now detect when users do that :P

Comment: my gosh you are right @HanletEscañ

Comment: @user3053430 works here http://jsfiddle.net/dxttgbnf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, The problem is caused by a typo because you have:

```
console.log(link.onlick);// onlick !!
```

Instead of:

```
console.log(link.onclick);
```

Here's the full code:

```
var link = document.createElement("a");
      var ce = function (e) {
        alert("A");
      }
link.onclick = ce; // Or link.addEventListener("click", ce);
link.text="Click me!!";
document.body.appendChild(link);
console.log(link.onclick);// here you will get function (e) { alert("A"); }
```

And now it works fine, **[here's a DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0r4p7tva/)**.

Comment: Now it logs `function(e){alert("A");}` for both `console.log`'s, but still does not call the function when I click the element.

Comment: @user3053430 : in fact all the problem is a typo! look at my EDIT.

Comment: After I fixed the typo it did console.log correctly, but the function still wasn't called when I clicked the link. I fixed it now, it was some sort of issue with the scope in which I used it.

Comment: Well, great then because it's working fine as you vcan see in the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the link that you create to the DOM before you bind the onclick event.

Once you do this you will no longer get undefined for the log of the onclick event.

```
var link = document.createElement("a");
var ce = function (e) {
    alert("A");
}
// Add link to page 
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.onclick = ce; // Or link.addEventListener("click", ce);
console.log(ce);
console.log(link.onclick);
```